# Converting UTM to Lat/Long without zone information

Tags: python, calculator, latitude-longitude, utm

I'm trying to convert UTM data (easting/northing) to lat/long, but the data I'm using doesn't have any zonal data.

I know I could just use an online converter but I have thousands of rows so this isn't viable.

The data is already in my notebook as a df, so ideally I want to replace the easting/northing columns with separate lat/long columns.

| Location_Easting | Location_Northing |
| --- | --- |
| 530,171.0000 | 179,738.0000 |
| 515,781.0000 | 174,783.0000 |
| 531,614.0000 | 184,603.0000 |

I tried this line of code but I get a TypeError saying the 'module' is not callable

`myProj = proj ("+proj=utm +zone=23K, +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")`

I know it asks for a zone but like I said I don't have this data.

Thanks in advance!

> I've now made an educated guess to my UTM zone (30U), but when I run the below code (updated) I'm told the module is still not callable - from my understanding of this link it should be appropriate for my project?
> https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/proj.html

`myProj = Proj ("+proj=utm +zone=30U, +north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")`

> I've since found code which will convert my metres and zone data to lat/long, but does anyone know how I can apply this to a whole dataframe (bus_stops)? posx should be column 'Location_Easting' and posy should relate to column 'Location Northing'

````
from shapely.geometry import Point

posx = 530,171
posy = 179,738.0000

# utm 24s is equivalent to epsg:32724
lon, lat = GeoSeries([Point(posx, posy)], crs='EPSG:32630').to_crs('epsg:4326')[0].coords[0] 

print(lon, lat)```

-7.483995602218547 0.0015423233602163576
````

Comment: It looks to me like without the zone information, this is an unsolvable problem.

Comment: What is `proj`? Judging by the error message, it's a module, and you are supposed to use something *in* that module. And you need the zone; without it, there are 60 points on the planet that correspond to your coordinates. However, if you know roughly where your points are supposed to be, you can make an educated guess — zones are 6 degrees wide, starting at zone 1 at 180°W and going eastwards (so London is straddling the border between zones 30 and 31).

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `Proj`, with a capital `P`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message saying that *module is not callable* is an evidence that you are trying to directly use the module when you should use a class from it.

Here is an declaration example using the `pyproj` module:

```
import pyproj

myProj = pyproj.Proj ("+proj=utm +zone=30 +north +ellps=WGS84"
                      " +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```